# How to write the program using "lm" command?

Tags: r, functional-programming, linear-regression, linear-programming

I tried to predict the t121 columns using the "lm" command below like this,

```
Model<-lm(t121 ~ t1 + t2 + ..... +t120, mydata)
```

In my data dependent variables are more than 100, So it's difficult for predicting each columns using "lm" command that's why i want to write the program for my data like this given below i written,

```
for(j in 120:179){
model[[j+1]]<-lm(t[j+1] ~ add1(t1:t[j]),mydata)
}
```

Instead of add1 place i used `add.bigq,sum` commands but these three commands are not correct please tell me what is the command suitable for that place?

Comment: Instead of `t1+t2+..` you can use `lm(t121~., mydata)`  It is better to show a small reproducible example.

Comment: please tell me clearly i didn't get

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(121:ncol(mydata), function(i) lm(mydata[[1]]~., mydata[c(i,seq(i-1))]))`

Comment: shall i use this command in the "for loop"? and where shall i add this command?

Comment: If you are using a `for` loop, you need to create a `list` object to store the output.  The `lapply` output is already a `list`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and reproducible example that anyone else
can simply copy and paste into their R session to run.  All library statements
and inputs need to be included.  Cut down your data to the minimum needed to
illustrate the problem and if your input is `x` then show it by displaying the
output of `dput(x)` in your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for general advice and see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more R oriented advice on how to ask a question on SO..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to write a loop that allows you to use `lm` with different formulas. The nice thing about `lm` is that it can take objects of the class `formula` as its first argument. Lets see how that works.

```
# Create a data set
df <- data.frame(col1=(1:10+rnorm(10)), col2 = 1:10, col3 = rnorm(10), col4 = rnorm(10))
```

If we want to run `lm` on `col1` as the dependent and `col2` as the independent variable, then we can do this:

```
model_a <- lm(col1 ~ col2, data = df)

form_b <- as.formula("col1 ~ col2")
model_b <- lm(form_b, data = df)

all.equal(model_a,model_b)
# [1] "Component “call”: target, current do not match when deparsed"
```

So the only thing that differed between the two models is that the function call was different (in `model_b` we used `form_b`, not `col1 ~ col2`). Other than that, the models are identical.

So now you know how to use the `formula` class to run `lm`. You can easily construct formulas with `paste`, by setting `collapse` to `+`

```
ind_vars <- paste(names(df)[-1],collapse = " + ")
form_lm <- paste(names(df)[1], "~", ind_vars)
form_lm
# [1] "col1 ~ col2 + col3 + col4"
```

If we want three different models, we can do a couple of things, for example:

```
lis <- list()
for (i in 2:length(names(df))) {
    ind_vars <- paste(names(df)[2:i], collapse="+")
    form_lm <- paste(names(df)[1], "~", ind_vars)
    lis[[i-1]] <- lm(form_lm,data=df)
}
```

Comment: Using `update.formula()` is probably better than the paste methods for any kind of complex formula.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that function.

Comment: @Laterow Thank you very much..i got it